# C#, How to append a namespace to many namespaces across multiple classes

Tags: c#, namespaces, project-management, dependency-management

I have a library that seems to conflict with another library that includes some variation of it as well. Resulting in some classes having multiple conflicting definitions. How would I resolve this?

Is there a way to add a namespace (to an existing namespace) for all the classes in one library to limit its scope, without having to go into each file and manually append it myself.

Comment: you can add namespace to exsisting, to avoid conflicts, encapsulate libraries in different namespaces and then use them in a separate namespace, which will act as container for the namespaces containing libraries

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to add `NewNamespace` to `CurrentNamespace`, just do a Find & Replace in your class library project for all classes, replacing `namespace CurrentNamespace` with `namespace NewNamespace.CurrentNamespace`.

Answer (score 0):

in this below link, you can get solution

http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/10/07/4502.aspx